# Two Getting Started Options in Setting Menu - SharePoint Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-settings

Found this issue on a new site I am working on and can't find a solution. I have two Getting Started Options in the settings menu.

The first link works and takes a user to the getting started page, but the second link doesn't work. How can I remove the second link?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This looks like Office 365 not SharePoint 2013 (on Premises). If yes then kindly change your tags in your question. Please check if Microsoft is working on that from settings. If yes then it will be resolved soon.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it. It isn't happening on other sites, so it must be something to do with this specific site?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed, found the option in Site Settings > Site Features. Simply had to deactivate it.